# is it possible to integrate overleaf platform with vscode?

Tags: editors, overleaf

> Is it possible to have a functionality where you have all changes by different users sync on the fly? Like on [overleaf.com](https://overleaf.com)

Comment: You mean https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/en/services/live-share/

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Git to integrate with Overleaf, and can install the command-line version of your preferred tex editor since you'll be using VSCode for UI.

This article should be useful:

https://medium.com/@rcpassos/writing-latex-documents-in-visual-studio-code-with-latex-workshop-d9af6a6b2815